# PowerShell import-module PSGet

Tags: powershell, module

Okay so I'm playing around with PSGet Utils and I really like the what's currently available in the repository.

I'm able to do the initial setup just find using the following command:

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
```

following that I installed a simple module: *Find-String* using the *install-module* command.

Once I close my shell and reopen it the command *find-string* is not recognized.

I have checked that PSModulePath env is set, and looked in the directory itself and it looks like it's actually there.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that in V5 PowerShell will ship with a built-in, different implementation called PowerShellGet and it will also have conflicting command names e.g. it has its own Install-Module.  Will be interesting to see how this shakes out between PSGet and PowerShellGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running PowerShell 2.0. 2.0 Doesn't have automatic loading of modules, so try importing it yourself with `Import-Module Find-String`